# Creating moments

Tags: web-services, web, google-plus, javascript

I'm trying to integrate an web app with Google+, and I want to share an article (both the content and the synthesized mp3). But there is some lack of good documentation, and It's difficult to find how I can Share the article.

**All code are here: http://jsfiddle.net/tuvGH/1/ But It's not working as my wep app.**

I believe, the logging operation is correct

**Logging:**

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
     client_id: clientId, 
     scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write'
     ], 
     immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
```

But when I try to share something, using examples in G+ Docs, I have no success.

**Share something:**

```
    var url = undefined;//'https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing';
    var payload = {
        "type": "http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",
    }

    if (url != undefined){
        payload.target = { 'url' : url };
    }else{
        payload.target = {
            "type": "http:\/\/schema.org\/MusicRecording",
            "id": "uniqueidformusictarget",
            "description": "A song about missing one's family members fighting in the American Civil War",
            "image": "https:\/\/developers.google.com\/+\/plugins\/snippet\/examples\/song.png",
            "name": "When Johnny Comes Marching Home"
        };
    }
    var request = gapi.client.plus.moments.insert({  
        'userId' : 'me',
        'collection' : 'vault',
        'resource' : payload});
    request.execute(function(result){
      console.log(result);
    });
```

After this request I have the following error

```
Object {
    code: 401, 
    message: "Unauthorized", 
    data: [
        domain: "global"
        message: "Unauthorized"
        reason: "unauthorized"
    ]
}
```

What's is wrong in the code above?

How can I share a article (the default example is not applied, because I'm not in the article page)?

Is that possible to share the Synthesized Article sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write` with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`. `plus.stream.write` is only usable for Google Apps for Business Google+ uses.

Update: [These tweaks](http://jsfiddle.net/LDmN2/) to your jsfiddle work to the point where the error is caused by bad metadata.

Comment: And why I got `Unauthorized` (401)?

Comment: I don't know. You are trying the jsfiddle I created without changing anything?

Comment: Yes, I'm using your jsfiddle!

Comment: Try revoking the apps access to your account and authing it again. Try a different browser too.